# Partial Fraction Decomposition in $ \frac{s^3-1}{(s^2+6)^2(s+12)^2} $.

Tags: partial-fractions

What special considerations do you need to take when decomposing the following fraction and why?

I'm trying to decompose the following:

> $$ \frac{s^3-1}{(s^2+6)^2(s+12)^2} $$

$$ \frac{s^3-1}{(s^2+6)^2(s+12)^2} = \frac{A}{(s^2+6)^2} + \frac{B}{(s+12)^2} $$

It obviously isn't correct. What to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When doing [*Partial Fractions*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/Alg/PartialFractions.aspx) you need to consider all of the increasing powers and should have (see the handy table in the link):

$$ \dfrac{s^3-1}{(s^2+6)^2(s+12)^2} = \dfrac{As + B}{(s^2+6)} + \dfrac{Cs + D}{(s^2+6)^2}+ \dfrac{E}{(s+12)} + \dfrac{F}{(s+12)^2} $$

You should arrive at:

- $A = \dfrac{758}{140625}$
- $B = \dfrac{6841}{562500}$
- $C = -\dfrac{67}{1875}$
- $D = -\dfrac{167}{3750}$
- $E = -\dfrac{758}{140625}$
- $F = -\dfrac{1729}{22500}$

Comment: Hmm, why do we use Ax+B form for $s^2+6$ an A form for $s+12$? Is it because $s^2+6$ is a quadratic term and $s+6$ is a linear term?

Comment: There is a set of rules and you can see a nice and handy table here http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/Alg/PartialFractions.aspx. If you recall those four simple rules, they always work.

Comment: Might have to burn this textbook and replace it with Paul's notes instead. +1

Comment: @Bob: It is always good to have more than one reference laying around! I would look for other books in the library to see if there are some that better suit your likes. Trust me, I have been there many a time! :-)